# Android Emulator slugish performance

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, emulation

I have intel i7 quad core with 4GB of ram but when I try to run my app on the emulator, God it takes a hell lot of time. Some times more than 5 minutes. I am not emulating any game or graphics intensive thing. I am learning android so just trying simple aps but still it is very slow. Moreover today I found this emulator has stop playing any music or sound I used the in the programs, I made previously. What can be the reason of this weird behaviour and slow speed.
How can I fix it? I am on Windows 7
PS: when I try to type in an app from user keyboard, the emulator doesn't take any input unless I use the emulator keyboard. Can I change its settings to take input from keyboard.
Regards

Comment: Have you been able to run your app on an Android device? If so, how is the performance?  Have you tried creating a new emulator in the AVD?

Answer (score 1):

Open android sdk manager, in extras, install "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager", and use x86 images (there are two available, one 2.3.3, one 4.0.3) provided by intel.

On windows, android SDK Manager only downloads the installer of IntelHaxm, so you have to go in and install it yourself.  Usually you can find it under
android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and install IntelHaxm.exe as admin.

4GB of RAM imho is not enough, windows 7 and eclipse together takes more than 2GB out on my system.  8GB is minimum and the more the better.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator has always painfully slow for me; I've never gotten any of the standard speed suggestions to work.  However, if you have a device available, testing directly on it is much, much faster.